# What are the differences between setInterval and requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript

What are the differences between `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame` in JavaScript and when and where do I use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `requestAnimationFrame` method is used to sync animations with the screen updates. The screen updates at a specific rate, for example 60 times per second. If you sync your animation updates so that they occur at that rate, the animation will look smooth.

Here is an example, where `anim1` runs at the rate of the screen, while `anim2` runs at a fixed rate. If you run the demo, you see that the left square moves smoothly, while the right square jumps a bit in the movement.

You can make the `setInterval` run more often to make it a bit smoother, but to make it support all different screens you would have to make it run faster than 120 times per second, which uses a lot more CPU than needed for most screens, and some browsers doesn't even support a rate that fast.

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(anim1);

window.setInterval(anim2, 25);

var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
var a2 = document.getElementById('a2');
var t2 = 0;

function anim1(t1) {
    a1.style.left = (50 + Math.cos(t1 / 500) * 30) + 'px';
    a1.style.top = (50 + Math.sin(t1 / 500) * 30) + 'px';
    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim1);
}

function anim2() {
    a2.style.left = (100 + Math.cos(t2) * 30) + 'px';
    a2.style.top = (50 + Math.sin(t2) * 30) + 'px';
    t2 += 0.055;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qu2Dc/2/

Note some differences:

- `anim1` calls `requestAnimationFrame` to catch the next update.
- `anim1` gets a parameter to use for timing, while `anim2` uses a counter.

Also, note that `setInterval` is supported in all browsers, but `requestAnimationFrame` is not. Internet Explorer 9 for example does not support it. If you plan to use it, it would be a good idea to check if it exists first, and use `setInterval` as a fallback.

Comment: @Mohammad: That's a value that is sent to the callback function for `requestAnimationFrame`, which tells the function how much time has passed. That's useful for making an animation move a certain distance over a certain time, as the function will be called at different rates on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval):

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

[requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame):

> The window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser call a specified function to update an animation before the next repaint. The method takes as an argument a callback to be invoked before the repaint.

Use the latter for animation and the former any time you want to call a function at a specified interval.

Comment: thanx , but what is the difference between them if the time interval for setInterval method was 16ms.