# Difference between window.requestAnimationframe and setInterval

Tags: javascript

I want to know the difference between window.requestAnimationFrame() and setInterval( , ) methods, I have used both and they work fine to me.

Comment: See: [what are the differences between setInterval and requestanimationframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574473/what-are-the-differences-between-setinterval-and-requestanimationframe)

Comment: @TheCoderBoy — Nothing is wrong with them. The question is extremely under-researched. (And you seem to be confusing votes about the quality of the question with votes about your worth as a human being. Don't do that.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

> The window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser calls a specified function to update an animation before the next repaint.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval):

> The setInterval() method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.